# How can we do finite-step signal sampling in practical?

Tags: discrete-signals, digital-to-analog

The signal has infinite length. We cannot sample it with a whole length. How can we truncate a infinite signal and sample it in finite step? And then how can we analyze it.

Comment: This is about signal processing fundamentals.  Truncating an infinitely long signal to a finite length is a process called **windowing**.  And sampling a continuous-time signals into sample values (with a finite step) is **sampling**.  How to analyze and process these samples is what DSP is all about.

Comment: Thx. I get the concept windowing. Could you recommend some resources for windowing? I just want to know the effects of windowing.

Comment: @FanjieKong your signals and systems basics textbook. If you're at a university, find the signals and systems basic lecture and the book/scriptum they use. Other than that, Oppenheim *discrete-time signal processing* is a classic, but goes way, way deeper; Bellanger's *digital processing of signals* might be more yours if you're into a bit of digital filtering, but not too much. As rbj said, these are *basics*, so essential every single introduction to digital signal processing will have it.

Comment: *" I just want to know the effects of windowing. "*  Windowing in the time domain corresponds to convolution in the frequency domain.  And that is as detailed as I plan to get about this.